# Implementing enhanced ecommerce with Google Tag Manager

Tags: php

I want to implement enhanced ecommerce with Google tag manager on Magento. I'm not a developer but i can play around with files and backend if instructed. I don't know how to send dataLayer for enhanced ecommerce through magento. I want to do it without any extension if possible. Can anyone help me figure this out? Any examples would be appreciated.
Thanks,
Gill

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you want to achieve? What have you tried, and what is the problem you encounter? And please edit the question and don'T comment the answers.

Answer (score 2):

**Setting it Up Without an Extension**

Setting this up (properly) without any serious development work may be challenging for a non-developer. You can't do this without an extension -- you can either take someone else's extension or you can effectively build out your own (isn't this always the case, though?).

**What needs to be done**

The basics involve placing the GTM tag (available from Google's Tag Manager dashboard) onto your Magento site. This can (and probably should be placed) immediately beneath the GA tag already on your Magento site, in *app/design/frontend/base/default/template/googleanalytics/ga.phtml*

The more challenging part for a non-developer will be producing the dataLayer and populating it with information.

**Customer Attributes in the dataLayer:** This is probably the easier portion and involves getting customer attributes for loggedIn (and just sessionData for not loggedIn) customers and writing them to a Javascript dataLayer array. See this ([I need to access customer information in JS](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/84488/i-need-to-access-customer-information-in-js/84500)) for a simple way of doing this (without the dataLayer array, that is).

**Order Data in the dataLayer:** This is the more challenging part, as it will require data to be written into the tag within the Success.phtml page. It will require both general order data as well as order item data, which requires iterating through the individual items of an order.

Why climb a mountain when you can jump a pebble? I once asked a veteran Magento developer (one of the better guys out there) to implement GTM and without blinking, he pointed to a freely available Magento extension.

**..there is still hope**

Considering you're not a developer (and even if you were, this probably isn't worth the trouble), you may want to take advantage of the Magento Connect store. There are a ton of Enhanced Ecommerce extensions that are either free or paid.

The integration should be fairly simple and GTM mainly requires standard Magento attributes and variables to be passed to the DataLayer.

- http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/google-tag-manager.html - FREE
- http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/google-tag-manager-integration-gtm.html - Paid
- http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/enterprise-google-tag-manager.html - Paid

Comment: Just wanted to add our extension to this list as well, since it includes basic support for Enhanced Ecommerce, such as transaction data and product tracking, so might be a bit easier to get up and running.

https://www.fontis.com.au/google-tag-manager-magento-extension - Paid

Comment: @ChrisNorton: is the enhanced ecommerce functionality segregated from the GTM functionality? Can each be disabled/enabled separately?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explaination @DavidLerner
I ended up using Qubit dataLayer for it.
One question i have for you is- if i place GTM script beneath GA script in app/design/frontend/base/default/template/googleanalytics/ga.phtm
would it not also fire Google Analytics script along with GA script fired by Pageview tag in GTM. This may result in registering two pageviews. ALso, would  it not place GTM script in the header instead of after opening body class.
Thanks again.

Comment: @Gill -- depends on your use case. GTM is not strictly for using Google Analytics. In fact, I don't personally use it for that -- I use for the dozen or so 3rd parties I'm working with. I haven't tested GA and GA via GTM so I can't tell you about duplication. As far as placement, Google recommends placing GTM immediately after the opening body tag.

Comment: @DavidLerner Yes, you can choose to enable or disable providing ecommerce data as you like. You can also individually choose to enable/disable product, category and customer data, along with the attributes for each that you want included in the data layer.

Answer (score 0):

To implement enhanced ecommerce with GTM you need to create the following data layers -:

```
- Product Impressions
- Product Clicks
- Product Detail Impressions
- Add / Remove from Cart
- Promotion Impressions
- Promotion Clicks
- Checkout
- Purchases
- Refunds
```

If you are a developer then you can use the following link to implement data layers on your Magento store

https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce

But if you are not or don't want to spend a lot of time then you can use the following extension -:

For Magento 1

http://www.scommerce-mage.co.uk/enhanced-ecommerce-tracking-with-google-tag-manager.html

For Magento 2

https://www.scommerce-mage.com/magento-2-google-tag-manager-tracking.html

Hope it helps

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The following link is a great starting point if you want to build the code by yourself without any extension

https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce

In regards to datalayer you see the following link which will give you basics about GTM datalayers

https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide

Hope it helps